# convert object to json data

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a console application , from that I want to sent the below given json as a request body for  an api . can any one suggest me how can I sent .

code

```
entity en = new ConsoleApplication3.entity();
            en.Size = "L";
            en.name = "test";
            en.view.Alignment = "left";
            en.view.IND = true;
            en.view.Object = "front";

string jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(en, Formatting.Indented);
```

here jsondata coming as

```
  {
 "view": {
 "Alignment": "left",
"InteriorIND": false,
"SteeringWheelPosition": "RHD",
"Object": "front"
},
 "Size": "L",
"Vin": "WVWZZZTST00000001"
}
```

JSON what I am expecting.

```
{
    "size": {
        "value":"L"
    },
    "view": {
        "alignment": {
            "value":"left"
        },
        "IND":true,
        "object": {
            "value":"xx"
        },
        "name": {
            "value":"test"
        }
    }
}
```

code what I have

```
string jsondata =??????

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new StringContent(jsondata) };
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "token");
req.Headers.AcceptCharset.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("UTF-8"));
req.Content.Headers.ContentType= new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(req);

// parse the response and return the data.
string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
return (dynamic)responseData;
```

Comment: By what logic would you convert a list of strings into that form?

Comment: What is a `List<string, string>`?

Comment: I'll assume that `List<string,string>` means `Dictionary<string,string>` or `List<(string,string)>`. It's still impossible to produce the required output without knowing how the values would have to be grouped

Comment: If you have any control over that JSON format I'd think you'd want to simplify it and remove all those `value` arguments and just have stuff like `"size": "L"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the JSON which you have given in your Question for that use this model,

then perform Assignments and then serialize it you will get the same json which you want.

```
public class Size
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Alignment
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Object
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class View
{
    public Alignment alignment { get; set; }
    public bool IND { get; set; }
    public Object @object { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Size size { get; set; }
    public View view { get; set; }
}
```